# Installed packages without doing conda activate

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda

I created a conda environment, and then without activating it I installed packages using conda and also some packages using pip via pip install -r requirements.txt

I have also already disabled that base should not be activated by default, so these packages got install in my user andnot in a virtual environment.

I want to remove all these packages from my user and then install in the conda env I created. I know how to install them in the conda env, but how to remove them from the user system i.e .my account where they are installed locally?. How to do it?

I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: isn't it `pip uninstall [package_name]`?